# How to access variables values used in Java Script from qt code

Tags: javascript, qt, variables

If I am having a qt code and I am running a java script using webkit , then how can I access  the variable value which is used in that script from my qt-code?

Answer (score 2):

Set the variable somewhere accessible (such as on the window object), and then use [`QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html) to get the variable.

In JavaScript

```
window.myint = 5;
```

In Qt:

```
const QVariant myvar = webview.page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("window.myint");
bool ok;
const int myint = myvar.toInt(&ok);
if (!ok)
  qWarning() << "Error getting int from JS";
```

This works with any type that can be passed between JavaScript and Qt.